# Keras backend BCE can't handle floats

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, types

I am trying to implement a loss function described [here](https://tiao.io/post/tutorial-on-variational-autoencoders-with-a-concise-keras-implementation/), which requires using `keras.backend.binary_crossentropy` instead off the classical `keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy`. The author says

> keras.losses.binary_crossentropy gives the mean over the last axis. We require the sum.

However, when I attempt to implement it in my code, it throws the error "TypeError: Input 'y' of 'Mul' Op has type float32 that does not match type int64 of argument 'x'." After trying out the functions in standalone code, I can confirm that `keras.backend.binary_crossentropy` throws an error when attempting to compare a float to an int.

Here is the code I am using to test this, based off of [this page](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/metrics/binary_crossentropy):

```
y_true = [[0, 1], [0, 0]]
y_pred = [[0.6, 0.4], [0.4, 0.6]]
loss_losses = tf.keras.losses.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
print(loss_losses.numpy())
loss_metrics = tf.keras.metrics.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
print(loss_metrics.numpy())
loss_backend = keras.backend.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)
print(loss_backend.numpy())
```

Additionally, when I try to run `loss_backend = keras.backend.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred)` with `y_pred = [[0, 1], [0, 1]]`, it throws the error "TypeError: Cannot convert 1e-07 to EagerTensor of dtype int32".

The only page I have found that attempts to describe how `keras.backend.binary_crossentropy` works is [this one](http://man.hubwiz.com/docset/TensorFlow.docset/Contents/Resources/Documents/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/binary_crossentropy.html), but it doesn't help me much.

Why is it doing this? Is there any way to work around this? Is this even the function I want to be using? The post is quite old and I don't think the author has updated it much.

Comment: your one-hot encoded labels should be floats, not ints, like 0.0 and 1.0

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I'm not one-hot encoding anything. My data is natively binary.

Comment: It does not matter, still they should be 0.0 and 1.0 values, not 1 or 0 (which are ints, not floats).

Comment: Yup, that did it